# SAP Spartacus: Event Service + GTM

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Hello we are using Spartacus 3.3 and have some trouble with the Event Service and GTM. If we got the documentation correct (maybe we did not) it a pure configuration topic and the available events can be registered for GTM and are thrown by the Spartacus standard. However if we subscribe e.g. to the PageEvent nothing happens. Event if we use the plain event service and listen for the PageEvents nothing is happening. Is this a bug or are we really forced to implemented the dispatching of the standard Events like PageEvent, NavigationEvent etc on our own?

```html
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BaseTmsModule.forRoot(),
    GtmModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    provideConfig({
      tagManager: {
        gtm: {
          collector: GtmCollectorService,
          gtmId: environment.googleTagManagerId,
          events: [
            OrderPlacedEvent,
            PageEvent,
            CartUpdateEntrySuccessEvent,
          ],
        },
      },
    } as TmsConfig),
  ],
})
```

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify your question? Are you asking if you need to listen to Spartacus' events in order for them to be dispatched to a TMS? Or, are you maybe saying the events are not being sent to your configured TMS? 
It would be useful if you can post any relevant custom configuration you may have provided to Spartacus.

Comment: Hi. We registered based on the Spartacus documentation for testing purposes the events OrderPlacedEvent, PageEvent, CartUpdateEntrySuccessEvent to be sent to the GTM (please see above). However nothing is sent to GTM besides the initial communicaton when accessing the store. 

In general there is the issue when we are listening with the EventService for those events e.g. eventService.get(PageEvent).subscribe(...) nothing is happing. 
Therefore our questions is if the standard events like PageEvent etc. be thrown automatically by Spartacus are is this a custom tasks?

Comment: Ok, let's first try to resolve this issue when events are not firing. Do you have any custom code related to events? In out-of-the-box Spartacus, these events are firing when you subscribe to them, e.g.
```ts
eventService.get(PageEvent).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
eventService.get(NavigationEvent).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```
They fire on initial page load, and when navigating between pages.
Did you make customization to the router? Or anything else that would influence the events?